# Split paths into lists

Tags: c#, arrays, list

Im struggeling to find a clever way of solving this problem.
I have a List containing paths for certain files.

The paths could look as such:

```
"Dinner/Soup/CurrySoup"
"Dinner/Soup/ChickenSoup/Croutons"
"Dinner/Beef/RibEye/Sauce/"
"Breakfast/Cereal/Kellogs"
```

I have to make a list containing the first part of the path for each String in the list, then a list containing the second part and so on. I believe using a splitter on each String is the way to go and adding it to an array before filling the lists. As far as I have understood, an array containing 3 substrings will be created if using `.Split('/')` of the first string described. I have come to the understanding that "Dinner" would be on `Array[0]`, "Soup" on `Array[1]` and so on… Now to the real problem. I can make it work for 1 String, but making it happen using variables to define the index of which list the substring should go to seems to cause me trouble when doing it for more than just one path and creating 10 lists to be able to deal with paths, that could be long (say 10?) seems like overkill. Any idea?

For those who wanted to see what I tried myself, here is what I did:

```
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
        List<string> listCategory1 = new List<string>();
        List<string> listCategory2 = new List<string>();
        List<string> listCategory3 = new List<string>();

        string s;

        list.Add("category1/category2/category3");
        list.Add("category1/category2/category4");
        list.Add("category6/category7/category8");

        foreach (String s1 in list) 
        {
            String[] a = s1.Split('/');

            int i = 0;

                if(i==0)
                {
                    listCategory1.Add(a.ElementAt(i));
                    i++;
                }
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    listCategory1.Add(a.ElementAt(i));
                    i++;
                }
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    listCategory1.Add(a.ElementAt(i));
                    i++;
                }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(listCategory1.ElementAt(0));
        Console.WriteLine(listCategory1.ElementAt(1));
        Console.WriteLine(listCategory1.ElementAt(2));
```

The console output being: category1, category2, category3.

I only managed to get the right answers for the first list. I thought about making a method taking in the string and calling the method multiple times.

Comment: Welcome to SO Niclas. May I ask you to format your question so it reads better? Also include some code of what you have tried so far. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit I think a sample input and output would help a lot too.

Comment: This seems a little bit like an XY problem to me... what is it you are trying to do with this list once you've created it?

Comment: Also, how are the paths stored? In an array, a list, a database table? Individual variables (why?)?

Comment: I want to create categories in Sharepoint based on the categories in the lists. Each list can easily be manipulated to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this approach:

```
var allTokens = paths.Select(p => p.Split(new[]{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
int maxLength = allTokens.Max(tokens => tokens.Length);
var allLists = new List<List<string>>(maxLength);
for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) allLists.Add(new List<string>());
foreach (string[] tokens in allTokens)
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
        allLists[i].Add(tokens[i]);
```

That's the most natural way to solve this. Here's the obligatory LINQ approach:

```
var indexLookup = allTokens
    .Select(arr => arr.Select((Token, Index) => new { Token, Index }))
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToLookup(x => x.Index);
```

Now you have a lookup which is similar to a dictionary but allows duplicate keys and also to lookup a key which doesn't exist(returns an empty sequence).

You get a `List<String>` for a given index in the following way:

```
List<string> index2List = indexLookup[2].Select(x => x.Token).ToList();
```

Result:

```
"CurrySoup" 
"ChickenSoup"   
"RibEye"    
"Kellogs"
```

If you want to know how to use the lookup-approach to get the `List<List<string>>`:

```
List<List<string>> allLists = Enumerable.Range(0, indexLookup.Count)
    .Select(i => indexLookup[i].Select(x => x.Token).ToList())
    .ToList();
```